# PHP Code in Other Block Won't Echo Variable

Tags: php, html

I have the following code that I am using to create a website:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml11          /DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
                if(isset($_POST["firstName"]))
                {
                    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]);
                    $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastName"]);
                    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
                    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
                    $cpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["cPassword"]);

                    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                    $salt = "";
                    for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
                    {
                        $rand = rand(0,35);
                        $salt = $salt . substr($chars, $rand, 1);
                    }
                    $hash = crypt($salt . $pass);
                    $query = "INSERT INTO users (salt, hash, email, fname, lname) VALUES ('$salt', '$hash', '$email', '$fname', '$lname')";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                    $cString = "";
                    for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
                    {
                        $rand = rand(0, 35);
                        $cString = $cString . substr($chars, $rand, 1); 
                    }

                }
        ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/common.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/thanks.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            echo $cString;  
        ?>
```

Why doesn't the value of `$cString` appear on my page? If I echo a string it shows, but when I echo the variable it doesn't show. Why is this?

Comment: Is `$_POST['firstName']` set?

Comment: echo $_POST['firstName'] and see if it's getting passed to you correctly.

Comment: Additionally, you should really look into using mysqli_* or PDOs rather than mysql_* functions.

Comment: fyi i don't think saving your salt in the db is a good idea.

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't see a problem with storing salt in the database, though he can actually pass salt as the second parameter to `crypt` :)

Comment: I can't echo any variable correctly from the previous php code block.

Comment: try using var_dump($cString) the value if NULL and datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue! Thanks for the help everyone, the issue was in the logic in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$cString` is only set if `$_POST["firstName"]` is defined.

Btw, you can use string dereferencing instead of using `substr`, so instead of:

```
$cString = $cString . substr($chars, $rand, 1);
```

You can do this:

```
$cString = $cString . $chars[$rand];
```

Comment: I thought $_POST["firstName"] was defined. Where I'm trying to echo the $cString variable I'm actually unable to echo any variable from the previous php code block. What's going on?

Comment: @user532493 in that case, you can be pretty sure `isset($_POST["firstName"])` returns `false`

Comment: I don't think that's the case because when I query the database to add the user's information, it all adds properly, which would imply that the $_POST fields are set.

Answer (score 0):

$cString is not set within the same scope.  Given this code, if you put

```
$cString = "";
```

right after the require_once line, it should work.

**Update**

You're most likely not showing your full code and `$cString` is constructed from within a function. Variables declared inside a function are not available outside. A few options:

1. return `$cString` when the function ends

   ```
   function my_fn()
   {
       $cString = 'abc';
       return $cString;
   }
   ```
2. declare `$cString` at the top and pass it by reference:

   ```
   $cString = '';
   function my_fn(&$cString) {
       $cString = 'abc';
   }
   my_fn($cString);
   ```

I've left out using `global` because it's not appropriate for your case I think.

Comment: Notwithstanding the PHP warning he might get, `echo null` or `echo ""` will yield the same net effect ... the value is not "seen" when echoed

Comment: PHP scoping doesn't work like that. The variable isn't unset when it exits the `if()` block. Not does this happen with fors or whiles; only functions, really.

Comment: @user532493 Hmm, I get it ... you're not showing the full code;  Updated my answer

Comment: I'm not defining $cString in a function, that's one of the few things I know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variable is inside the `if`, when you call it outside it wont exist. You only need to declare the variable outside the `if` (at the start of your code would be perfect).